# Linting inline scripts

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor, eslint, prettier

My coworker and I are having a problem with indenting. He uses Atom and I use VSCode. We're both using the same eslint and prettier configs (using eslint-plugin-prettier). But Atom's auto-formatter wants to unindent inline scripts:

```
<script>
var foo = bar;
</script>
```

while Code insists on indenting them:

```
<script>
  var foo = bar;
</script>
```

This is going to make a proper mess of our git repository. How do I convince VSCode not to indent, or Atom to indent?

Edit: to be clear, we don't care which convention we adopt, just that our editors do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Prettier is not supporting formatting HTML and it's up to the HTML formatter that is builtin in each editor, or you could find a common one as an extension.